# Convert dd image file to iso

Tags: iso, qemu, disk-image

I've a disk dump image (`.dd`) of an old version of X-Linux ([X-Linux R41](http://www.dmp.com.tw/tech/os-xlinux/r4.htm)).
Is there any chance to successfully convert this `.dd` image to a `.iso`? I've tried this conversion through a forensic tool, but what I've got is a corrupted image, where no OS is found.

I need an iso because I've to emulate this OS through QEMU.

Comment: qemu should boot the raw image if you use it as a hard drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"dd" is "iso" for all intents and purposes. It's a raw image, and as mentioned above, it will boot in qemu or kvm (assuming it isn't corrupt) if it is a raw image.

Example, if you take a hard drive with Ubuntu installed, located at `/dev/sdc`, and use the command:

```
dd if=/dev/sdc bs=8M of=/home/me/sdc.raw
```

You can then boot `/home/me/sdc.raw` using qemu or KVM.

Comment: I also created a .img file using dd in linux. This img file doesn't open in Windows unless I use separate software like OSFMount. So it is still worth explaining how to convert the img file to an iso file.